# Batting right and left handed every alternate ball in cricket

Tags: cricket

A switch hit is acceptable in cricket. But if a batsman wants to disturb the line of the bowler by playing right and left handed every alternate ball, would it be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Laws of Cricket which *explicitly* prevents this, but I'd say that it very quickly becomes time wasting by the batting side and would be subject to the penalties detailed in [Law 41.10](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/unfair-play).